# Can LinkedIn REST API access user activity feeds?

Tags: linkedin-api

Does LinkedIn provide a REST API functionality similar to **company** updates...

- https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/company-pages#company_updates

...but for the **user** activity feed? Such as these feeds:

- https://www.linkedin.com/in/emilychangbloomberg/detail/recent-activity/
- https://www.linkedin.com/in/rbranson/detail/recent-activity/

Comment: LinkedIn [writes](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/53170/using-stackoverflow-for-api-support?lang=en) `In an effort to boost support for our developer community, we moved our online support forum from the Developers site to StackOverflow. [...] Tag question with the #linkedin hashtag so LinkedIn engineers will see them.` So, it will be interesting to see if these LinkedIn engineers will comment on this in any way...

Comment: Two months have passed, and no response form the "LinkedIn engineers" who "will see" questions tagged with #linkedin. LinkedIn only provides support for paying customers; other developers can only ask questions on Stack Overflow and then hope that the SO community will help. Typical big company behavior.

Answer (score 0):

**ATTENTION: This is no longer valid since Linkedin deprecated this service and is no longer granting access to the activity feed through its API.**

Before REST API Call, OAuth (Application must be authorized and authenticated before they can be fetch data from LinkedIn or get access to member data.)
                        - Get Permission
                            -   Client ID(API Key) and Client Secret.
                            -   Your application directs the browser to LinkedIn's OAuth 2.0 authorization page where the member           authenticates. After authentication, LinkedIn's authorization server passes an auth code to your application.
                            -   Sends this code to LinkedIn and LinkedIn returns in access token.
                            -   Application uses this token to call APIs on behalf of the member.

```
                        - Step 1: Get Client ID (API Key) and Client Secret
                            -   OAuth setting - Add redirect URL
                        - Step 2: Generate an Access Token 
                            -   https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id={your_client_id}&client_secret={your_client_secret}
                            -   {
                                    "access_token": "AQV8...",
                                    "expires_in": "1800"
                                }
                        - Step 3: Make API Requests
                            - Make API requests by including an Authorization header with your token in the HTTP call to LinkedIn's API.
                            https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/guide/v2/shares/activity-feed

                            -   GET /v2/jobs HTTP/1.1
                                Host: api.linkedin.com
                                Connection: Keep-Alive
                                Authorization: Bearer {access_token}

                                https://api.linkedin.com/v2/activityFeeds?q=networkShares&count=2

                                Available v2 APIs include:
                                    r_liteprofile (replaces r_basicprofile)
                                    r_emailaddress
                                    w_member_social (replaces w_share)
                    */
```